# Android Studio Show 2 Tool Windows

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio used to show both logcat and terminal but something went wrong. Now it is only showing 1 window at a time. I have been clicking view -> tool windows to get these to show. When I click logcat while in terminal it closes the terminal and vice versa. I am just wondering how to make 2 windows show at once as before. I would like both log and terminal to show at the bottom of the screen side by side. I am using a Mac computer.

Pictures:[image][image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though late, I just faced same issue and resolved using following approach.

Select
Android studio ->View -> Appearances -> Tool Window Bars.
That will show tabs for all tool windows like Terminal, Debug  & Logcat and makes easy to navigate across tool windows.